# Receiving an error: <identifier> expected

Tags: identifier

I'm trying to read a text simple file containing text of a small poem and then send each line to the output file, preceded by line numbers.

I haven't figured out how to add the line numbers yet, but I keep receiving the identifier expected error when I try to just send each line to the output file. Here's my code:

```
import java .io.File;
import java.ioFIleNotFoundException; 
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        //Construct Scanner Objects for input files
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(new File("JackBeNimble.txt"));

        //Construct PrintWriter for the output file
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("JBN_LineByLine.txt");

        //Read lines from the file
        while(in1.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line1 = in1.nextLine();

            out.println(line1); 
        }
    }
    in1.close();
    out.close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo for FileNotFoundException (should be `java.io.FileNotFoundException`) and your closing } before `in1.close()`; is misplaced; it should be after `out.close()`;  Note that you are not handling any exceptions neither.

Answer (score 0):

I spotted a few issues,

```
// Added the throws FileNotFoundException
public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    //Construct Scanner Objects for input files
    Scanner in1 = new Scanner(new File("JackBeNimble.txt"));

    //Construct PrintWriter for the output file
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("JBN_LineByLine.txt");

    //Read lines from the file
    while(in1.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line1 = in1.nextLine();

        out.println(line1); 
    }
   // Close in the main body.
   in1.close();
   out.close();
}
```